# Determining variance due to measurement errors between two data sets of the same population

Tags: anova, sampling

I have a set of *n* objects, and for each object *i*, the property *C(i)* has been measured. The measuring device has low precision, so the value actually recorded from the measurement is *C(i) + X(i)*, where *X(i)* is a random variable. *C* is also expected to be randomly-distributed around a mean if you pick a random object, but every individual object's *C(i)* is fixed.

*C(i)* has been measured twice for each object, which results in two recorded values, which we'll call *C(i) + X(i,1)* and *C(i) + X(i,2)*. (I don't understand the notation well enough to describe this more correctly.)

The problem I'm trying to solve is to estimate how much of the variance in these *2n* observations (two measurements for each object) is due to the variance in the objects' properties--*C(i)*--and how much is due to the measurement device--*X(i)*. The data can be assumed to be normally-distributed. The only two estimates I could come up with are not mathematically rigorous, and I'm not sure what the actual way to do it is. Here's what I tried:

1) Finding the variance of an *n*-observation set consisting of the average of the two measurements for each object, then finding the variance of the original *2n*-observation data set, and finally dividing the former value by the latter to get a % variance explained by *X(i)*.

2) Individually finding the variance of [*C(i) + X(i,1)* , *C(i) + X(i,2)*] for every *i* and averaging all of those variances together. Divide that by the variance of the original *2n*-observation data set to get a % variance explained by *X(i)*.